# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL on all Facebook Plugins

Tags: plugins, registration, facebook-comments

I have both the facebook comment plugin and the registration plugin in my site.  They throw a "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL" error in safari and chrome.

This is fine where it doesn't affect other javascript but my registration plugin is in a modalView and the errors kill off the javascript displaying the modalView causing it to not be hidden by default.  Oh, and I don't like errors in my consoles.

Here is the full error: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.mydomain.com from frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?. Domains, protocols and ports must match.